# Is it possible to share an Office 365 Outlook Calendar with the beta version of the Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

As part of our new onboarding process, I was looking at using the new (beta) Graph API to share an Outlook calendar. The Microsoft documentation [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/versioning-and-support.md#beta-version) shows how to get the permissions already established, how to update those permissions, and how to revoke permissions, but I don't see a way of actually setting up the initial permissions and sending the invite.

Does anyone have an idea what the https call would like to share a calendar with basic read permissions to a new user?

Answer (score 0):

The docs are actually published here based on that github source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/versioning-and-support

There are two stages. 
- when YOUR application needs to define the permission scopes it requires either at App Registration within portal.azure.com OR in code
- when the USER signs into your application and then is prompted to consent the permissions for the application to access Graph APIs on behalf of their user identity

If you are using MSAL libraries, this is all done for you. I'd encourage you to take a look at the Getting Started https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started pages where there are tutorials that start from scratch or quick starts you can download to look at. There are also some great training modules here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/browse/?products=m365%2Cms-graph&resource_type=module&roles=developer